# How to format a nested list comprehension line?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to produce a list comprehension that receives a list of numbers and adjust the numbers depending on the value in the list.

For example:

If the number in the list is > 255 I want the list comprehension to take the value 255
If the number in the list is < 0 I want the list comprehension to take the value 0
Any any other value (between 0 and 255) should be accepted by the list comprehension.

The code I am using is:

```
num = [260, -2, 124]

adj = [[0 if (n <= 0) else 255 if (n > 255) else n in n if n in range(1,255)]] for n in num)

print(adj)
```

I have tried the above but I am getting syntax errors:

```
File "/Users/home/Dropbox/Python_general_work/Python FB Groups/hex_converter.py", line 54
adj = [[0 if (n <= 0) else 255 if (n > 255) else n in n if n in range(1,255)]] for n in nums)
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can you advise how to structure the list comprehension so it works.

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing a final ``else``. There is no clause to say what happens when none of your ``if``'s match. Also, ``n in n if n in range(1,255)`` doesn't make logical sense – it means ``(n in n) if (n in range(1, 255)``, but an integer cannot be "in" another integer/itself.

Comment: What do you want to happen if a number is *not* in the interval [0, 255)? Do you actually want each number to be wrapped into a list or was that a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`adj = [0 if n <= 0 else 255 if n >= 255 else n for n in num]`

You don't need the additional `range(1, 255)` in the list comprehension as the conditions before that ensure that the number is in the range [1, 255).

Comment: The value 255 is handled by neither of the original conditions – it is not smaller/equal than 0, not larger than 255, and not in the ``range(1, 255)``.

Comment: Followip question : Would it be possible to extend the list comprehension with another argument . For example if I add a while statement to the end of the comprehension : adj = [0 if n <= 0 else 255 if n >= 255 else n for n in num while c in range(0,5)].   I find it hard to find detailed explanations of list comprehensions.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to extend the if else use cases. Python's [Conditional Expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) were designed for such use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `min` for cropping it from top and `max` for cropping it from bottom:

```
adj = [min(255, max(0, n)) for n in num]
```